# Force browser to refresh page from flash game

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have flash game which communicate with server. If something goes wrong I want to show popup where will be said. Something is broken press ok button to refresh game.

```
btnHolder.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, refreshPage);

private function refreshPage(e:MouseEvent):void
{
...
}
```

How can I do this ? Is this even possible ? Or max I can do is just show popup with text "refresh your browser".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use ExternalInterface, like:

```
ExternalInterface.call("document.location.reload", true);
```

Could that work for you?

Comment: Better handle the reload in a javascript function and call that function. That way you can add a log in it & such.

Comment: True, I was trying to point out that he can call javascript functions from AS3, I suppose he can figure out what to do with that.